# Windows not asleep but monitor will not turn on

Tags: windows-10, display, power-management

This is one of those almost-impossible to Google questions because the results are flooded with results about 'sleeping' computers and monitor problems.

My Windows 10 laptop monitor is fine, as is the external HDMI monitor. Additionally, my computer is not asleep. However, in my "Power & sleep settings" I have my screen set to turn off, when plugged in, after 15 minutes. I have it set to never go to sleep, when plugged in.

The problem is, on occasion, when I come back to the computer with the black screen, I can't get the monitor to turn back on. I hit keys and nothing. Again, the computer is *not* asleep and I can see the back light on the keyboard as well as the power and HDD lights. The only thing I can do is hard reboot, which I don't like to do.

Besides changing the setting so that the screen is never turned off, is there anything that can be done here? Thank you.

Comment: If you just let it sleep, couldn't you use the power button to "wake" it? It wouldn't fix the issue for you, but certainly better than hard reboot...

Comment: When it's in that condition, do your CAPS/NUM/Scroll lock keys work (ie: toggle their respective keyboard LEDs)?  You say you "hit keys" and nothing happens. Which key combinations have you tried? Specifically, have you tried a Ctrl-Alt-Del when it's in that state?  When in that state, have you tried powering off/on the monitor, or unplugging/plugging it back in (power)?

Comment: If it's asleep then it's easy to wake, but I don't always want the machine to sleep; I just want the screen to go black.
@Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I hit the "shift" and "space" keys, which normally bring the screen back. I've also tried a few others, but I haven't check caps/num/scroll lock keys. I'll give that a go if it happens again. I'm assuming you want to see if the keyboard is 'alive.' Ctrl-Alt-Del does not work. Unplugging and reconnecting the HDMI cable, or powering the monitor, also does nothing for the external monitor.

Comment: right now I can't remember how often this works but when my monitor won't come back on I turn the monitor Off, remove the power cable from the back of the Monitor, remove the data cable and rub the data pins with my finger like I am trying to short them together.